# How to write a htaccess rewrite rule where you can load a website inside a folder as it would be loaded from the root

Tags: .htaccess, web, mod-rewrite, server, url-rewriting

I have the following folder structure

```
ROOT (loaded on domain.com)
+campaigns
 |+campaign1
   |-assets
   |-index.php
 |-campaign2

.htaccess
index.php
stuff.php
```

At the moment to access the website inside the folder `campaign1` i would have to enter in the URL address bar: `domain.com/campaigns/campaign1`

What should i put in the `.htaccess` file so that when you put
`domain.com/campaign1` the browser loads and shows everything from `domain.com/campaigns/campaign1` but of course without visibly changing the URL in the address bar.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It is usually easier to adjust your directory structure to mirror the URLs you want rather than hack .htaccess.  Why not just promote campaign1, etc  to the root directory and remove the campaigns directory?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller This is what i am trying to avoid. Problem is that there are tens of campaigns already at root level and they need to all be organised in one folder, but all the original links to them that have been indexed or share, need to still be accessible. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Presumably it's not literally "campaign<number>"? Or is it?

Comment: If you are reorganizing the directories I would change the URLs to include the new subdirectory and implement redirects for each of the existing campaigns.

Comment: @MrWhite it is not, it was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following in the root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite. This is a *general* version if the "campaign" subdirectories are not known (or too many):

```
RewriteEngine On

# 1. Abort early if request already maps to a file or directory
RewriteRule ^campaigns/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# 2. Check if the first path-segment maps to a directory in "/campaigns` directory
# If so then internally rewrite the request to that subdirectory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/campaigns/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ campaigns%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Where `$1` is a backreference to the captured subgroup in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

> i would have to enter in the URL address bar: `example.com/campaigns/campaign1`

Since `campaign1` is a directory you should be requesting `campaign1/` (with a trailing slash) otherwise mod_dir is going to issue an external redirect to append the trailing slash.

> when you put `example.com/campaign1` the browser loads and shows everything from ...

Likewise, you should be requesting `example.com/compaign1/` - with a trailing slash - and the above rule assumes that you are. It won't do anything if the trailing slash is omitted and you will get a 404. (If you are expecting third party requests where the trailing slash is omitted then you will need to manually issue a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash *before* the above rule.)

---

**UPDATE:**

> What if i know the name of the campaign folder that goes into the campaigns folder? basically if i want to manually add the rule but campaign specific?

Yes, you can do this. In fact, if the number of campaigns you wish to rewrite in this way is limited then this may even be preferable since it avoids the filesystem check.

You may also be able to remove the second rule (second part of section#1 above) that prevents further processing should a file or directory be requested. ie. Remove the following:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
> RewriteRule ^ - [L]
> ```

So, instead of (or before) section#2 above you could do the following...

For a single campaign:

```
# 2. Rewrite campaign to "/campaigns" subdirectory
RewriteRule ^compaign1/ campaigns%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

For multiple campaigns:

```
# 2. Rewrite campaigns to "/campaigns" subdirectory
RewriteCond $1 =campaign1 [OR]
RewriteCond $1 =campaign2 [OR]
RewriteCond $1 =campaign3
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ campaigns%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Note that it is specifically `$1 =campaign1`, the `=` is a prefix-operator on the *CondPattern*  (2nd argument) itself. The `=` operator makes it an exact string match, not a regex.

Or, using a regex and *alternation*:

```
# 2. Rewrite campaigns to "/campaigns" subdirectory
RewriteCond $1 ^(campaign1|campaign2|campaign3)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ campaigns%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

(Although this could be combined into a single directive.)

---

**UPDATE#2:**

Add this before the internal rewrites to add a trailing slash at the end of the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Note that all internal links *must* already linking to the URL *with* a trailing slash. This redirect is only for the benefit of search engines and third party links that might be referencing the non-canonical URL without a trailing slash.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I will try this today and report back. What if i know the name of the campaign folder that goes into the campaigns folder? basically if i want to manually add the rule but campaign specific?

Comment: @alex.b I've updated my answer with regards to manually listing the campaign folder(s).

Comment: How would i go around the trailing slash? I just tried your solution and seems to be working, but as you pointed out, it only works if there is a trailing slash at the end. How would i make it work without it or maybe add the slash automatically? Thank you so much!

Comment: I believe this will do the trick: 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
    RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]